# Fdisk expert mode not available

Tags: fdisk

It seems that the eXpert mode in fdisk is no longer available. When I try sudo fdisk -x, terminal returns "fdisk: invalid option -- 'x'"
I have fdisk from util-linux 2.24.1
Is this a "feature"?

Comment: What feature from eXpert mode you are missing ?

Comment: And in which version did you have a commandline option to directly go to expert mode? As far as I can remember you always needed to input `x` to the command prompt once started to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **x** option is available only in interactive mode not as an parameter to fdisk command. For example:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

Then press **x** at the Command (m for help): and the prompt should change to:

Expert command (m for help):

I'm using same version of fdisk.

```
fdisk -v
fdisk from util-linux 2.24.1
```